# TypeError: $ is not a function when using Firebug console directly

Tags: jquery, firebug

My page has jQuery referenced, as other code is already running correctly. But I need to add some new code, and decided to try testing the selector directly in Firebug before writing the code. So I go to the console and type in my selector:

```
$("h3:contains('Keynote')");
```

Now, this may or may not be a valid selector. I don't care, at this point. When I hit enter, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: $ is not a function

Now I know if you get that error in code that's actually running on your page, it's usually either because jquery is not referenced or running (which we know it is) or because there are conflicts with another library. But would code that's run directly in the console be affected by that? And if so, how do I get around it for testing purposes? Do I have to skip testing this way in Firebug and just write the code in my file and test from there?

If it helps, when I click on the link to the error message, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `$` with `jQuery`? `jQuery("h3:contains('Keynote')");`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could do that in Firebug. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept so you get points.

Comment: `$` is a function from Firebug API. If you type `$` in Firebug's console, it takes precedence over `$` from the page code. https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried replacing the `$` with `jQuery`?

```
jQuery("h3:contains('Keynote')");
```

My first guess would be a conflict which this should handle.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a different alias when your are playing with multiple javascript libraries. jQuery has solved this by using the following code:

```
var myAlias = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then you can use wherever you want the new alias "myAlias".

Comment: -1: Good answer, just not to *this* question :( `"So I go to the console and type in my selector:"` the key being they needed a simple *console solution* (i.e. use `jQuery` instead of `$`).

Comment: I think that it is always a good practice to use an example in order to make the person to think his best solution.. Both are proper answers, perhaps i should be more comprehensive..